# Why I get 403 for the site request Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem with Jmeter . When I open homepage of https://demo.nopcommerce.com/ I get 403 but for other endpoint of this site I do not get this error. Should I add cookies for such case? SOrry , I just new to it...[image]

will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, perhaps you recorded some [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which shouldn't be there for not-authenticated user.

[image]

Try disabling the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) which is under your request /-60 and if you will be able to get [HTTP status code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) add another HTTP Header Manager and copy the headers there one by one until you will find the one which is causing the problem.